# Method that print all value greater than or equal to value passing in method in Binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I want print all value greater than or equal to value passing in method in Binary search tree

```
public static void reverseOrder(TreeNode node, int n) {
    if (sizeOfBinaryTree(node) < n) {
        System.out.print(n);
        return;
    }
    if (node == null) return;
    reverseOrder(node.right);
    System.out.print(node.data);
    reverseOrder(node.left);
}
```

but I couldn't it was print all values
any one can help me please

Comment: What values were missing?

Comment: From the description of your problem, I would expect to see a comparison such as `node.data >= n` somewhere in your code. That seems to be missing.

Comment: any value passing in method

Comment: Can you present an example of a tree with a value of `n` and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void reverseOrder(TreeNode node, int n) {
    if (node == null) return;
    reverseOrder(node.right);
    if(node.data >= n){
    System.out.print(node.data);
    }
    reverseOrder(node.left);
}
```